# What is the difference between the two ways of declaring variables in a for in statement?

Tags: javascript

if i use for in, i always use const to declare variable

```js
const array = ["a","b","c"]

for (const value in array) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

but the other way is use global scope variable using let

```
let value
const array = ["a","b","c"]

for (value in array) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

the result is same, but i don't know which way is better. Could you explain the difference between the above two methods in terms of memory or other cost?

Comment: Usually go for the smallest scope

Comment: you can change the `let value` inside the loop but not `const value`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, using a `for...in` loop to iterate the indexes of an array [shouldn't be done](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/5648954), instead, use a regular `for` loop for that. If you want to iterate the values of an array, use something like a `for...of` or `.forEach()` loop.

The first difference between your two examples is probably the most obvious one. In your first example you've declared your variable with `const`, so assigning it to a different value within the body of your for loop cannot be done. Whereas with `let` you can reassign it if you need to.

For example, the below will throw an error if you try and reassign `value`

```js
const array = ["a","b","c"];
for (const value of array) { // updated to for...of loop
  value = 1; //  this will throw!
  console.log(value);
}
```

Whereas the below code will work fine:

```
let value
const array = ["a","b","c"];
for (value of array) {
  value = 1; //  works perfectly fine
  console.log(value);
}
```

---

The other differences between your two examples are to do with scoping of the `value` variable. In the first one, a new `value` binding is created for each iteration of your array and invocation of the `for` loop body, meaning that independent `value` variables are essentially created for each iteration and scoped to the current block. This means that `value` cannot be accessed outside of your for loop. In your second code block, `let value` is declared outside of your for loop, so naturally, it can be accessed outside of your `for` loop.

```js
const array = ["a","b","c"];
for (const value of array) {
  console.log(value);
}
console.log(value); //  this will throw!
```

Compared with `value` that is declared outside of the loop:

```js
let value;
const array = ["a","b","c"];
for (value of array) {
  console.log(value);
}
console.log(value); //  this will work and log "c"
```

In addition to this, declaring `value` outside of your `for` loop means that the same global `value` variable that you declared will be updated on each iteration of your for loop, resulting in each invocation of your for loop body sharing the same variable. The implications of this can be seen if you have a [closure/function inside of your loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

The below logs `a`, `b`, `c`, because when the `setTimeout()` callback function is declared in the loop it uses the unique binding created for `value` for that particular iteration of the loop:

```js
const array = ["a","b","c"];
for (const value of array) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(value);
  }, 500);
}
// logs:
// a
// b
// c
```

This logs `c`, `c`, `c`, because when the callback function is created, it uses the globally shared value of `value`, and by the time the `setTimeout()`s execute, the for loop would have completed (so value would be `"c"` by that time):

```js
let value;
const array = ["a","b","c"];
for (value of array) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(value);
  }, 500);
}
// logs:
// c
// c
// c
```

---

As using `const` (or `let`) in the `for` loop statement directly needs to create a new binding for each invocation of your loop, you could say that it takes up more memory, but that small amount should be negligible and something not to worry about. Moreover, JavaScript engines most likely will optimize for this, so I would suggest declaring your variables inside the loop statement directly, as it will minimize issues with leaking variables into the surrounding scope outside of your `for` loop.